# Send HTTP request with proxy and certificate

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, proxy

There is this page which I can only access with proxy and certificate.

So is there a way to send a http request with proxy and certificate?

I have tried `https-proxy-agent` but it does not seem like it supports certificates.

```
    const agentWithProxyAndCertificate = (proxy, certificateFilePath) => {
      const cert = fsSync.readFileSync(certificateFilePath);
      return new HttpsProxyAgent({
        key: cert,
        cert,
        ...parseUrl(proxy),
      });
    };
    const httpsAgent = agentWithProxyAndCertificate(US_PROXY, `${__dirname}/cert.pem`);
    const client = new HttpClient({ agent: httpsAgent, cookieJar: true });
```

Is there any other way to do this in Node.js?

Comment: Set the proxy system/os wide and use your "normal" app without the proxy stuff. Let the OS handle that.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of that approach, iis there any other way to do it within the code?

Comment: Write a custom proxy that supports certs or fork it. Its not that hard.